# What is the return type of SQL's AVG() function

Tags: sql, jdbc, types, double, average

I am trying to copy one table's content into another, in the following way:

```
        sql ="INSERT INTO customer (nev, quantity, frequency) SELECT "
                + "?,COUNT(?),AVG(?)"
                + "FROM tempcustomer GROUP BY ? ORDER BY COUNT(?) DESC";

        preparedStmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, "nev");
        preparedStmt.setString(2, "nev");
        preparedStmt.setString(3, "pont");
        preparedStmt.setString(4, "nev");
        preparedStmt.setString(5, "nev");

        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

I get the following error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'pont'
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3971)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at Sample.main(Sample.java:101)
```

I am new to JDBC, thanks in advance!

Comment: You may not pass column names as parameter to a query. Only values. The column names are needed by the database to prepare the query, which is the whole point of a prepared statement. If the database doesn't know what to select, on what to group or order, it can't possibly create an execution plan.

Comment: You are right, it solved the issue thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the arguments.  As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html):

> The `SUM()` and `AVG()` functions return a `DECIMAL` value for exact-value
>   arguments (integer or `DECIMAL`), and a `DOUBLE` value for
>   approximate-value arguments (`FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`).

You can coerce a string argument to a number by treating it as a number:

```
AVG(? + 0)
```

However, a value such as `'pont'` will be converted to 0 which will be included in the average calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much! `'pont'` is an INT column  name, which works in regular selection

Comment: @K.Fia . . . If it is a column name, then your query could only produce that error based on a trigger.